# how to call Rest Webservice of .net from IOS?

Tags: .net, ios, json, xcode4.5

Recently i have started work in Consuming REST Webservice of .NET to my IOS.
Following way i have created the webservice in my .NET

Service1.cs File

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace WcfJsonRestService
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                    UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
        public Person GetData(string id)
        {
            // lookup person with the requested id 
            return new Person()
                       {
                           Id = Convert.ToInt32(id), 
                           Name = "Leo Messi"
                       };
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have googled the things but its very complex to understand as i have never been to web service concept in iOS..so can any one please let me guide that how and where i can call this web service that just simply display a return string in on label of iOS device(IPAd) with Xcode 4.5.just a demo app i want to build

Comment: RESTful web services are so nice because it is language agnostic how they are accessed. Google "how to issue HTTP-GET in language x". Issueing the GET to the correct url will return a json string containing your data which you need to parse. Then look up "how to parse JSON in language x".

Answer (score 3):

You've got the WCF JSON endpoint, now you need to consume the JSON produced by that endpoint in your IOS application. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.kotancode.com/2011/04/26/backing-your-ios-app-with-wcf-json-web-services/) on how to do just that.